# Using InterpolatingFunction in equations

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I tried to use InterpolatingFunction in another ODE, but it doesn't work, because it seems for Mathematica that 2 functions are unknown instead of one.

```
 sol1 = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 2}, y[x], {x, 10, 15}]
   sol2 = NDSolve[{f'[t] == With[{x = t}, Evaluate[sol1]], f[0] == 2}, 
  f[t], {t, 0, 10}]

 During evaluation of In[89]:= NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables,
 {f[t],y[t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined. >>
```

So, can I somehow use my function $y[x]$ in the next equation?.. 
The final goal is to solve Delay differential equation with time-dependent delay using method of steps manually.

Comment: If you change the second line to `sol2 = NDSolve[{f'[t] == (y[x] /. sol1[[1]]) /. x -> t, f[0] == 2}, f[t], {t, 0, 10}]` you get a result (albeit with warning messages). Is it close to what you expect to get?

Comment: do `sol1 = y[x] /. First@NDSolve`.  You are then left with the problem that the  range is {10,15} in the first equation and {0,10} in the second ..

Comment: @george2079 thanks, forgot replacing, such a stupid question... {10, 15} and {0, 10} is misprint, of course it should be {0, 15}.

Answer (score 1):

You need either to use the [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html):

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 2}, y[x], {x, 0, 15}];
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == With[{x = t}, Evaluate[sol1]], 
    f[0] == 2}, f[t], {t, 0, 10}];
```

Note that I also changed the ranges for the first solution.

Or (that's why you have an issue) you need to use [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 2}, y[x], {x, 0, 15}];
sol2 = NDSolve[{f'[t] == First@With[{x = t}, Evaluate[y[x] /. sol1]], 
    f[0] == 2}, f[t], {t, 0, 10}];
```

Comment: Ok, I got it, but what's the meaning of replacing here? Am I right, that I need to use ReplaceAll because $y[x]$ is considered as defined function, whereas $sol1$ could be undefined?

Comment: No, because in *Mathematica* `NDSolve`, `NSolve`, `Solve` and other similar functions return the solutions in terms of replacement rules. So you need `/.` or introduced in *Mathematica* 10 `*Value` functions.